# deallocating NSArray Vs releasing NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm quite confused. I'm using the animation frames to make the objects move. Here's the code:

```
campFireView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 63)];


campFireView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:   
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire01.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire02.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire03.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire04.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire05.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire06.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire07.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire08.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire09.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire10.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire11.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire12.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire13.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire14.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire15.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire16.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire17.png"], nil];


campFireView.animationDuration =2.5;

campFireView.animationRepeatCount = 0;


[campFireView startAnimating];

[bgview addSubview:campFireView];

[campFireView release];
```

Please tell me how to `release` such kind of `NSArray`? I've not used any `alloc` in the code, so how to `release` this array as it is causing a lot of leak in my code.

Comment: Is `campFireView` an ivar? I don't see you declaring it anywhere here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to `release` such kind of `NSArray`?

You don't. Your leak is most likely caused elsewhere in your code because what I see here should not leak by itself.

Comment: BoltClock is right. Everything related to that NSArray in your code will be taken care of by the autorelease pool.

Comment: okies so one more thing i wanna ask...

m using the same code with 60 frames along with the camp fire..is it fine???

or is it the cause of leak??

Answer (score 1):

That NSArray is autoreleased. If you're really leaking, it is from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to release the NSArray. You use it with `NSArray arrayWithObjects`. That means you don't own the object, therefore you don't have to release it.

Answer (score 0):

No leak with array, arrayWithObjects: gives an autorelease object.

i think you are releasing campFireView in dealloc also. you need to make retain type property for campFireView and release it in dealloc insted here.